# Does XML-RPC in general allows to call few functions at once?

Tags: python, soap, xml-rpc, xmlrpclib

Can I ask for few question in one post to XML-RPC server?
If yes, how can I do it in python and xmlrpclib?

I'm using XML-RPC server on slow connection, so I would like to call few functions at once, because each call costs me 700ms.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.python.org/library/xmlrpclib.html#multicall-objects

Comment: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately Bugzilla xml-rpc server doesn't support muticalling.

Comment: For this I can't provide any help ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not possible support of multicall makes any difference to you depends on where the 700ms is going.

How did you measure your 700ms?

Run a packet capture of a query and analyse the results. It should be possible to infer roughly round-trip-time, bandwidth constraints, whether it's the application layer of the server or even the name resolution of your client machine.

Comment: I traced my script and found that it read 1 char at time. Maybe thats why result is so slow. I'm using python's xmlrpclib library, and didn't intentionally set buffer to 1 char. Must find where this can be changed.