# Improving speed of xmlrpclib

Tags: python, xmlrpclib

I'm working with a device that is essentially a black box, and the only known communication method for it is XML-RPC. It works for most needs, except for when I need to execute two commands very quickly after each other. Due to the overhead and waiting for the RPC response, this is not as quick as desired.

My main question is, how does one reduce this overhead to make this functionality possible? I know the obvious solution is to ditch XML-RPC, but I don't think that's possible for this device, as I have no control over implementing any other protocols from the "server". This also makes it impossible to do a MultiCall, as I can not add valid instructions for MultiCall. Does MultiCall have to be implemented server side? For example, if I have method1(), method2(), and method3() all implemented by the server already, should this block of code work to execute them all in one reply? I'd assume no from my testing so far, as [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/xmlrpclib.html#multicall-objects) shows examples where I need to initialize commands on the server side.

```
server=xmlrpclib.ServerProxy(serverURL)
multicall=xmlrpclib.MultiCall(server)
multicall.method1()
multicall.method2()
mutlicall.method3()
multicall()
```

Also, looking through the source of xmlrpclib, I see references to a "FastParser" as opposed to a default one that is used. However, I can not determine how to enable this parser over the default. Additionally, [the comment on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3343497/546311) mentions that it parses one character at a time. I believe this is related, but again, no idea how to change this setting.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the bulk size of your requests or responses are very large, it's unlikely that changing the parser will affect the turnaround time (since CPU is much faster than network).

You might want to consider, if possible, sending more than one command to the device without waiting for the response from the first one. If the device can handle multiple requests at once, then this may be of benefit. Even if the device only handles requests in sequence, you can still have the next request waiting at the device so that there is no delay after processing the previous one. If the device serialises requests in this way, then that's goingn to be about the best you can do.